# How can I search on a field and return the object

Tags: mongodb

I made a beer matching dating app for a school assignment. Unfortunately am I having a bit of trouble finding out how to search in my database on a template injected number as object.

I've tried this I read on [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)

The database looks like this :

```
beerProfile: Object
 ↳24589: Object 
  ↳name: "Heineken"
   img: "https://untappd.akamaized.net/site/beer_logos/beer94130_52756_sm.jpeg"
   description: "Heinken is a beer"
   bid:"24589"
```

So beerProfile is an object and has the object 24589 inside it. Inside the 24589 object are name, imd, description and bid.

I tried to use the find() function. ( the collection is called users )

```
db.collection('users').find( { [24589]: [{name: [Heineken]}] }, { name: 1, bid: 1 }, done);
```

And I also tried :

```
db.collection('users').find( { $text: { $search: 24589 } }, done);
```

I would like to make it return the object values of the 24589 object. Does anyone how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your "schema" became unnecessarily complex by using a variable (24589) as a key. You should change it to something like this:

```
beerProfile: Object
 ↳beer: Object 
  ↳name: "Heineken"
   img: "https://untappd.akamaized.net/site/beer_logos/beer94130_52756_sm.jpeg"
   description: "Heinken is a beer"
   bid:"24589"
```

Then you can use a simple find():

```
db.collection('users').find( { "beer.bid": "24589"})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is a really good solution thank you! How would you add a second beer to the beer profile ? As duplicates aren't allowed. Or is there a workaround ?

Comment: @Root_ish, then you have to make it an array which can hold multiple beer objects. `beer: [ { name: "Heineken" bid: 24589 }, { name: "Bud" bid: 24590 } ]`, etc.